Embed on web page a Twitter Video, just like a YT video
(Complete beginner here, fighting to assemble some web page.)
If a "copy video address" in X (Twitter), I get something like:
https://x.com/i/status/1814440131505598541
If I get the embed code from a You Tube video, I get something like:
<iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aNfD0dbiPSY" title="Oriented circles and relativistic geometry II | Wild Linear Algebra 35 | NJ Wildberger" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share" referrerpolicy="strict-origin-when-cross-origin" allowfullscreen></iframe>

My question is the following.
Using Javascript/html/css, if I wish to put the X (Twitter) video on web page, and have exacly the
same (or similar if not possible) embed result, as using the You Tube embed code, how can I achieve that ?
Thank you
(I do not know where to start from. I am grateful for any pointer or help)

https://help.x.com/en/using-x/how-to-embed-a-post

try
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-media-max-width="560"><p lang="en" dir="ltr"><br>Gym teacher helps a disabled girl to dance with her classmates.<br>Just look at her smile!❤️</p>&mdash; Eddie (@Health00810) <a href="https://twitter.com/Health00810/status/1814440131505598541?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">July 19, 2024</a></blockquote> <script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>


Thank you, Muhammed and  Offbeatmammal that seems to work  :-)  (I only detected some noticeable delay before displaying the video: I'm not sure if that can be eliminated).
